# IE7: Image that appears on mouseover is going under surrounding divs (Z-order not working properly)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have been tasked with the unfortunately job of getting a website to work in IE7, when this code is run in IE7, it renders larger images on mouseover *underneath* surrounding divs, when it should display on over the top. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

I am trying to work out what I have to do to get it to work properly in IE7 (I've tried to make the code as simple as possible by simplifying what is currently in the website to it's basic elements, but apologies that it is still long).

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}

.homelist{ 
margin-top: 10px; 
width: 490px; 
float: left;  
}

.attorneyhomediv
{
width: 226px;
float: left;
background-color: #d2c8c5;
position: relative;
}

.atty1 .bigroll .big-photo1, .atty2 .bigroll .big-photo2, .atty3 .bigroll .big-photo3, .atty4 .bigroll .big-photo4
{
display:none;
z-index: 10;
}

.atty1 .bigroll:hover .big-photo1, .atty2 .bigroll:hover .big-photo2, .atty3 .bigroll:hover .big-photo3, .atty4 .bigroll:hover .big-photo4
{
width:175px; 
padding:13px 12px 6px 13px; 
display:block !important; 
position:absolute; 
top:-10px; 
left:68px; 
color:#000; 
background:#fff; 
z-index: 10;
}

.alignleft {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homelist">
<div class="attorneyhomediv atty1" >
<a class="bigroll" href="#">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-110" alt="image01" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg" width="67" height="67">
<div class="big-photo1" style="z-index:500"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg"></div>
</a>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
</div>
<div class="attorneyhomediv atty2" >
<a class="bigroll" href="#">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-112" alt="image02" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg" width="67" height="67">
<div class="big-photo2" style="z-index:500"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg"></div>
</a>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have a reset in css ?

Comment: No, this is exactly the code I am running and getting these results. So no reset.

Comment: can you try with this reset  ? [mayer reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Just checked and it doesn't make any difference I am afraid.

Comment: wait, i'm trying your code on IE10>emulate IE7 and after night night time ^^

Comment: Thanks, this is killing me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fix

add jquery library to your source

and add this code

```
<script>
$(function() {
       var zIndexNumber = 1000;
       // Put your target element(s) in the selector below!
       $("div").each(function() {
               $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
               zIndexNumber -= 10;
       });
});
</script>
```

like that

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}

.homelist{ 
margin-top: 10px; 
width: 490px; 
float: left;  
}

.attorneyhomediv
{
width: 226px;
float: left;
background-color: #d2c8c5;
position: relative;
}

.atty1 .bigroll .big-photo1, .atty2 .bigroll .big-photo2, .atty3 .bigroll .big-photo3, .atty4 .bigroll .big-photo4
{
position:absolute;
display:none;
z-index: 10;
}

.atty1 .bigroll:hover .big-photo1, .atty2 .bigroll:hover .big-photo2, .atty3 .bigroll:hover .big-photo3, .atty4 .bigroll:hover .big-photo4
{
width:175px; 
padding:13px 12px 6px 13px; 
display:block !important; 
position:absolute;
top:-10px; 
left:68px; 
color:#000; 
background:#fff; 
z-index: 10;
}

.alignleft {
float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homelist">
<div class="attorneyhomediv atty1" >
<a class="bigroll" href="#">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-110" alt="image01" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg" width="67" height="67">
<div class="big-photo1" style="z-index:500"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg"></div>
</a>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
</div>
<div class="attorneyhomediv atty2" >
<a class="bigroll" href="#">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-112" alt="image02" src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg" width="67" height="67">
<div class="big-photo2" style="z-index:500"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/01/10/14/33/hot-air-balloon-241642_150.jpg"></div>
</a>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    
</p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
       var zIndexNumber = 1000;
       // Put your target element(s) in the selector below!
       $("div").each(function() {
               $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
               zIndexNumber -= 10;
       });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it is working! Unfortunately when I put it in the actual website, it knocks out a couple of other things (although it looks like I could fix it). Would you know how to target this only inside the div 'homelist'?

Comment: change $("div").each(function() { by $(".homelist").each(function() {

Comment: Just trying to get this working, I will let you know. Thanks so much!

Comment: bye, cya here may be :)

Comment: Wow, it does work. The only problem is with so much other stuff going on the page, it doesn't seem to execute until the page loads (it takes nearly 30seconds in IE7, but less than 5 in Chrome, go figure) - would you suggest any work arounds for that quickly? But either way thanks so much!

Comment: try to load jquery library before the end of body, can you try to track what is loading with firebug ? may be not this cause this

Comment: aha, sorry firebug on IE : ), hit F12 on IE for track